# updatedb within chroot

Tags: chroot

I'm running a Debian wheezy under chroot and I notice that updatedb doesn't work !
I think it's because of missing entries inside fstab. Am I wrong ?

Any advice to fix this ?

Comment: *How* does it not work?

Comment: Nothing happens !! But I suspect it's a mount problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question a dew days ago while I had the same problems.

After what I have found out- the problem comes (in my case) during limitations of debootstrap.
Possible solution : try another installation-method for your chroot.